# Why clang report same types as incompatible?

Tags: c++, clang

I want to use the pointer returned by `malloc()` as the name of a multi-dimensional array, thus I cast the pointer. When compiling, I got an error:

```
clang++ -o cast cast.cpp
cast.cpp:29:12: error: assigning to 'int8_t (*)[width]' from incompatible type
      'int8_t (*)[width]'
  int8line = (int8_t (*)[width])(array);
           ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

But compiling with `icpc` on the same platform (OS X) and `g++/icpc` on Linux, no error is thrown.

**UPDATE**: The width is variable, thus can not be `const`.

---

Tested compilers are:

> Mac OS X
>
> ```
> icpc (ICC) 17.0.4 20170411
>
> clang --version
> Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
> Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
> Thread model: posix
> ```
>
> Linux 2.6.32:
>
> ```
> icpc (ICC) 14.0.0 20130728
> g++ (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731
> ```

---

The result should be:

```
icpc -std=c++11 -o cast cast.cpp && ./cast 5
0   1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8   9

0   1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8   9
```

---

minimum compilable code (updated):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    cerr << "needs one argument\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  long width = atol(argv[1]);

  int8_t *array = static_cast<int8_t(*)>(malloc(sizeof(int8_t)*2*width));
  for (int i = 0; i < 2*width; i++)
    array[i] = i;

  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
      cout << static_cast<int>(array[i+j*width]);
      if (i < (width-1))
        cout << '\t';
    }
    cout << '\n';
  }

  cout << '\n';

  int8_t (*int8line)[width];
  int8line = (int8_t (*)[width])(array);
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
      cout << static_cast<int>(int8line[j][i]);
      if (i < (width-1))
        cout << '\t';
    }
    cout << '\n';
  }

  free(array);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `long width = 5;` width should be const

Comment: It's very strange to use `malloc` in C++, and almost as strange to *cast* it in C. This leads me to believe that your question is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and the answer to the X part (the most significant part of your problem) might best be found by either using `new int8_t[width]` or `std::vector<int8_t>`.

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd11dba2af9b5213) compiles under GCC but not clang. It's possible behavior like that is the reason clang won't accept pointers to variable length arrays.

Comment: `int8_t array[2][width];` is not allowed in Standard C++ . Nobody's been able to make a proposal for it that doesn't break when mixed with other C++ constructs

Comment: There's no malloc in this code (and nor should there be)

Comment: @Seb Yes. I find [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#multidim-arrays) on isocpp.org. But since the memory required is determined after arguments are passed, will it be more efficient to allocate them all rather than `new each row separately?

Comment: `array[i] = i;` causes undefined behaviour, the left operand of `=` must designate an object  (but you have provided an expression designating storage that does not contain any object)

Comment: Why use `malloc` in a C++ program??

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because it's regular non-constant variable. Other compilers may recognize immutability of this variable but that kind of guess is not something specified by standard.

If you make the variable `width` constant, it should work:

```
const long width = 5;
```

Comment: Maybe, but then how to explain `long width = atol(argv[1])` will not change the result?

Comment: @Eli4ph : because the variable still remains effectively constant. This is detected by some of the compilers as an extension but generally not required by standard specification.

Answer (score 0):

Having a non-constexpr `width` is called [varaible length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and is not standard C++.

The type of `int8line` is therefore in a weird state, `int8_t (*)[width]` is not an actual type, resulting in the compiler producing the confusing error message.

As [Zbynek Vyskovsky - kvr000 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44350597/4832499), using `const long width = 5` will work, this is because it makes `width` a constant expression, something known at compile time. This makes the array not a variable length array.

You should probably use `std::vector` instead.